# Build Failed with Auth0-lock in React Native Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native, auth0

I'm trying to use Auth0 Lock with my Android React-Native app. I followed the setup instructions [here](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock-android), but I get the following error upon building:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.auth0.android:lock-react-native:+ as no versions of com.auth0.android:lock-react-native are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/m/.m2/repository/com/auth0/android/lock-react-native/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/Users/m/.m2/repository/com/auth0/android/lock-react-native/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/auth0/android/lock-react-native/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/auth0/android/lock-react-native/
         file:/Users/m/git/this-or-that-app/node_modules/react-native/android/com/auth0/android/lock-react-native/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/Users/m/git/this-or-that-app/node_modules/react-native/android/com/auth0/android/lock-react-native/
         file:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/auth0/android/lock-react-native/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/auth0/android/lock-react-native/
     Required by:
         thisOrThatApp:app:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.332 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I notice these lines:

```
file:/Users/m/git/this-or-that-app/node_modules/react-native/android/com/auth0/android/lock-react-native/maven-metadata.xml
file:/Users/m/git/this-or-that-app/node_modules/react-native/android/com/auth0/android/lock-react-native/
```

I have a hunch that the proper place from which this should be installed is the node_modules folder, but gradle is looking inside the react-native module when it should be looking inside react-native-lock-android. This might be a problem with a gradle configuration. Any tips on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the documentation for react-native-android on the Auth0 site is out of date. Use the instructions for setup on the github repo: https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock-android.

But the repo still a bit out of date and isn't completely clear on how to modify MainActivity.java. So, for anyone coming to this post later, here's my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.thisorthatapp;

import com.auth0.core.Strategies;
import com.auth0.facebook.FacebookIdentityProvider;
import com.auth0.lock.react.LockReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "thisOrThatApp";
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether dev mode should be enabled.
     * This enables e.g. the dev menu.
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    /**
     * A list of packages used by the app. If the app uses additional views
     * or modules besides the default ones, add more packages here.
     */
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        LockReactPackage lockReactPackage = new LockReactPackage();
        lockReactPackage.addIdentityProvider(Strategies.Facebook, new FacebookIdentityProvider(this));
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            lockReactPackage
        );
    }
}
```